# Internet Explorer 11 and Html5 Sound playback

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, internet-explorer-11

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCXKZ/) that has both a regular html5 `<audio>` tag in it for playback, as well a a call to the javascript `Audio()` function.  As expected, in Chrome/Firefox/IE10 these work, but in IE11 (came with windows 8.1 yesterday) neither of these methods work and I get a `"Error: Not implemented "` exception.  I haven't yet seen any documentation that Audio doesn't work on IE11 - is my installation just screwed up, or do others with IE11 see this as well?

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NCXKZ/)

Also, heading over to http://html5test.com/ in IE11 indicates that the sound element is supported, but that no codecs work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE11 was running in this case on Windows 8.1 Pro N.  Installing the [media pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744) solved this for me, even though I think it's insane that html5 features of the browser need this addition to work properly, and Microsoft doesn't list the Media Pack as having any impact on any other features (like IE11 or html5) [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835517).

Comment: I can confirm is also the case on a new windows 10 installation (European N version does not come with windows media pack). I would use Try Catch around your statement to trap this error.