# Html5 audio not playing in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-canvas, createjs

In IE11 the audio in my html5 game does not work. It works fine in chrome and other browsers. An example of how I register and play the sounds is below.

Any idea how to fix it for IE 11?

[Link to the game](https://www.wisc-online.com/arcade/games/natural-science/life-science/643/infection-control-and-prevention)

```
 var assetsPath = gameData.assetsPath || "";

    manifest = [

                { src: assetsPath + "PlayBall.mp3", id: "PlayBall" },//|PlayBall.ogg

    ];

    preloader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    preloader.installPlugin(createjs.SoundJS);
    preloader.addEventListener("complete", addTitleView);
    preloader.loadManifest(manifest);

    createjs.Sound.registerSound({ src: assetsPath + "PlayBall.mp3", id: "PlayBall" });//|PlayBall.ogg


    startB.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            //playball!

            myCrowd.play({ offset: 0, loop: 4, pan: 0 });    // options as object properties


            createjs.Sound.play("PlayBall");
            createjs.Sound.play("Cheer");

            addGameView();

        });
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this topic ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455970/internet-explorer-11-and-html5-sound-playback

Comment: yeah i tried to install that pack and it wouldn't install said something like it was irrelevant for my system... not sure the exact words was a few hours ago.